# is it okay to say "don't step your slippers on the mat"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

> [step](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/step) 2 ●●● S3 W3 verb (stepped, stepping) [intransitive always +
>   adverb/preposition]
>
> 1 to raise one foot and put it down in front of or behind the other
>   one in order to walk or move
>
> step forward/back/down/into etc
>
> He stepped back to let me through.
>
> I stepped outside and closed the door.
>
> Mr Ives? Please step this way (=walk in the direction I am showing
>   you).
>
> 2 to bring your foot down on something SYN tread British English
>
> step in/on etc
>
> I accidentally stepped in a puddle.
>
> You’re stepping on my foot.

---

"**Step**" is an intransitive verb.

So we can say "**to step on the mat**" but not "**to step your slippers on the mat**".

Say, Your kid can walk barefoot on the mat but he can't walk on the mat while wearing his slippers.

is it okay to say "**don't step your slippers on the mat**"? or maybe "**don't step on the mat while wearing your slippers**"?

Comment: As you say, _step_ is intransitive - so, no, you don't _step your slippers_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question: Is it okay to say "don't step your slippers on the mat"? or maybe "don't step on the mat while wearing your slippers"?

Answer: No, it is not.

- Don't **step on the mat** in your slippers.
- Don't **walk on the ma**t in your slippers.

Those are the ways it would be said.

For items of clothing including shoes, we say: in your shoes. If you are wearing them, you are "in them".

Answer (score 1):

No. You don't "step" your shoes, slippers or your feet.

It sounds like you want to say "don't step on the mat in your slippers".